# How to point tiles.xml from web.xml

Tags: web-applications, struts2, tiles2

I'm new to struts2,In fact new to web application development just started developing a sample application. Currently I'm using struts tiles concept in my project. Here is how I am referring to tiles.xml in my application.

```
 <listener>
            <listener-class>
                org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
            </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
            <param-name>tilesDefinitions</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

I'd like to place tiles.xml to resources folder of application, despite of placing it inside web-inf folder. How can I refer to that in web.xml.

Comment: I just want to organize my folders in my web application, so that resources has as the stuff, like *.xml(struts.xml,tiles.xml), *.properties(MessageBundle.properties). How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving configuration files from their original location is something dangerous, and shold be examined case by case.

But usually you can use a trick: place a stub xml configuration file in the place where it is expected to be, that contains only the `include` of the real file, located out of the WEB-INF (or inside it but in another location):

```
<struts>
   <include file="..\struts.xml"/>
</struts>
```

As described here: http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/struts-1-solutions.html

For properties it's harder... be careful

Comment: gratitude, for your valuable suggestion. I realized that it's not needed to change its position from web-inf.

Comment: I'm not sure this isn't a bad thing to do. Tiles is able to loads it's definitions even from a DB, I don't think it is too eyebrow raising to move the xml configuration file anywhere.

Comment: You say "Why not?", I say just "Why ?"... it violates YAGNI :)))

Comment: While from DB it could make sense: you could change the definition at runtime. On file system instead, even if outside the web application, it would be hard to change something on a production server without a release... +1 for DB idea :)